# What does "pay the graces" mean?

Tags: idioms, word-usage

Have the Three Graces actually been paid? Is that the origin? I found it in the lyrics for a song, where it doesn't seem to make sense at all:

> I had an impulse to clear it all away
>   oh I used the tactics, make everybody pay
>   just something that I knew I had to do
>   But through it all I kept my eyes on you
>
> Oh, I keep it all clean
>   I've paid the graces there
>   No Kings of Misuse
>   No sellers of flesh
>   Just something that I knew I had to do.

The Song's called "The Kill", so I guess someone's been killed and the killer leaves the scene clean, or didn't kill the person too gruesomely, but how does that have anything to do with paying the graces?

Comment: To my ear, "I've kept it all clean" suggests that the "graces" in question are the *social* graces. I don't know if the "paying graces" idiom is anything like current, though; it's the sort of thing that sounded old when my grandmother said it 50 years ago.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about one particular example, where only the songwriter knows what was meant (if indeed there was only one clear meaning intended, which is rare in lyrics and poetry). This is not a phrase in common use.

Answer (score 2):

[THE KHARITES (Charites) or Graces](http://www.theoi.com/Ouranios/Kharites.html),

> The three goddesses of grace, beauty, adornment, mirth, festivity, dance and song. A number of "younger Kharites" presided over the other pleasures of life, including play, amusement, banqueting, floral decoration, happiness, rest and relaxation.

So it means that the singer paid due to the goddesses

---

***Context***

"The Kill" - Joy Division

> Moved in a hired car,
>   And I find no way to run,
>   Adds every moment longer,
>   Had no time for fun,
>   Just something that I knew I had to do,
>   But through it all I left my eyes on you.
>
> I had an impulse to clear it all away,
>   Oh I used the tactics, make everybody pay,
>   Just something that I knew I had to do,
>   But through it all I kept my eyes on you.
>
> Oh, I keep it all clean,
>   **I've paid the graces there**,
>   No kings of misuse,
>   No sellers of flesh,
>   Just something that I knew I had to do,
>   But through it all I kept my eyes on you,
>   Yeah through it all I kept my eyes on you,
>   But through it all I kept my eyes on you.